# etable() to word output

Tags: r, fixest

I'm trying to export etable() output to word but it seems like it only outputs to latex, any tips?

```
library(fixest)
lms<-feols(mpg~csw0(cyl,disp,hp),mtcars)

etable(lms)
```

Answer (score 1):

`etable()` cannot export to Word but [`modelsummary`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html) can:

```r
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)
library(flextable)

lms <- feols(mpg~csw0(cyl, disp, hp), mtcars)

names(lms) <- rep("mpg", 4)

# If you want the table as-is:
# modelsummary(lms, stars = TRUE, output = "table.docx") 

# if you want to customize the table with `flextable`
modelsummary(lms, stars = TRUE, output = "flextable") |> 
  autofit() |> 
  save_as_docx(path = "table.docx")
```

[image]